# Specified cast is not valid using one to many relationship with EntitySet

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm working on a Windows app targeting .net 4 that pulls in order information from several platforms. I need to store the data in a local database and have decided to use LINQ to SQL, at the moment my Order class has a fair amount of code to handle that data sent be each platform, so I've been using decorators to add attributes to the class rather than using the designer in Visual Studio.

It seems to be mostly working, however when querying the DB for an Order it only successfully returns the main order data and trying to enumerate the Items EntitySet it throws an "Specified cast is not valid." exception. The program will correctly insert the order into the Orders table and the order lines/items into the OrdersLines table, it will also read the OrdersLines table and return correctly populated OrderLine objects.

[Database layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d2Qv.png) I have a foreign key constraint on OrdersLines linked to Orders.orderID

Classes:

```
[Table(Name = "Orders")]
public class Order
{
    [Column(Name="orderID",IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=false)]
    public string OrderID;
    [Column(Name = "sourceID")]
    public int SourceID;
    [Column(Name = "statusID")]
    public int StatusID = 1;
    [Column(Name = "externalOrderID")]
    public string ExternalOrderID;
    [Column(Name = "deliveryName")]
    public string Recipient = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryCompany")]
    public string Company = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryAddress1")]
    public string Address1 = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryAddress2")]
    public string Address2 = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryAddress3")]
    public string Address3 = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryTown")]
    public string Town = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryCounty")]
    public string County = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryCountry")]
    public string Country = "";
    [Column(Name = "deliveryCountryISO")]
    public string CountryISO = "";
    public Country RMCountryData;
    [Column(Name = "deliveryPostcode")]
    public string Postcode = "";
    public Int64 TotalWeight = 0;
    public ShippingType ShippingType = ShippingType.Standard;
    public ShippingDestination ShippingDestination = ShippingDestination.International;
    [Column(Name = "email")]
    public string Email = "";

    private EntitySet<OrderLine> _Items = new EntitySet<OrderLine>();
    [Association(Name = "FK_OrdersLines_Orders", Storage = "_Items")]
    public EntitySet<OrderLine> Items
    {
        set
        {
            this._Items.Assign(value);
        }
        get
        {
            return this._Items;
        }
    }

    public Order() {  }

    public void Save()
    {
        OrderDataContext context = new OrderDataContext(String.Format(Settings.Default.ConnectionString, Settings.Default.DBUser, Settings.Default.DBPassword, Settings.Default.DBServer, Settings.Default.DBName));
        context.Log = Console.Out;
        var query = from o in context.Order where o.OrderID.Equals(this.OrderID) select o;
        var line = from l in context.OrderLine where l.OrderID.Equals(this.OrderID) select l;

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            context.Order.InsertOnSubmit(this);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var customerOrder in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customerOrder.OrderID);
                foreach (var orderItem in customerOrder.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(orderItem.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[Table(Name = "OrdersLines")]
public class OrderLine
{
    [Column(Name = "localLineID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int LocalLineID;
    [Column(Name = "orderID")]
    public string OrderID;
    [Column(Name = "lineID")]
    public Int64 LineID;
    public Int64 ProductID;
    [Column(Name = "sku")]
    public Int64 SKU;
    [Column(Name = "name")]
    public string Name;
    [Column(Name = "quantity")]
    public int Quantity;
    [Column(Name = "weight")]
    public Int64 Weight;

    public OrderLine() { }

    public OrderLine(Order Parent, Int64 SKU, Int64 LineID, string Name, int Quantity)
    {
        this.OrderID = Parent.OrderID;
        this.LineID = LineID;
        this.ProductID = 0;
        this.SKU = SKU;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
        this.Weight = 0;
    }
}

public partial class OrderDataContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<Order> Order;
    public Table<OrderLine> OrderLine;

    public OrderDataContext(String connString) : base(connString) { }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the line "foreach (var orderItem in customerOrder.Items)"

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.SingleKeyManager`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, V& v)
at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[] keyValues)
at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.TryGetCachedObject(Object[] keyValues, T& cached)
at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute(Object instance)
at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.Load()
at System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately I am having some trouble figuring out your issue. Could you post the code that calls Linq To SQL?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I didn't make it clear enough, its the inner foreach loop in Order.Save() which throws the exception. If I break after the 2 LINQ queries and inspect the results query will contain a properly populated Order object except the _Items will fail to enumerate when expanded throwing the exception, the OrdersLine query will return the full list of order lines for that order with all the OrderLine objects properly populated.

Comment: The code is in my first post in the block of code marked "Classes:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see in your Database layout (screenshot from SQL Server Management Studio?), the "weight" and "lineID" columns are defined as "Allow Nulls".

But into the `OrderLine` class definition you posted, the `LineID` and `Weight` properties are not `Nullable` :

```
[Table(Name = "OrdersLines")]
public class OrderLine
{
    // ...
    [Column(Name = "lineID")]
    public Int64 LineID;
    // ...
    [Column(Name = "weight")]
    public Int64 Weight;
```

Linq2SQL is certainly expecting these properties to be `Nullable` and it could explain why you get an `Specified cast is not valid` : Assignments could fail because columns database types are not matching C# properties types.

Try to use this code instead :

```
[Table(Name = "OrdersLines")]
public class OrderLine
{
    // ...
    [Column(Name = "lineID")]
    public Int64? LineID;
    // ...
    [Column(Name = "weight")]
    public Int64? Weight;
```

**Edit**

I also noticed that `orderId` is `nvarchar(30)` and `localLineId` is `int`. It could be a problem for Linq2SQL while generating a join SQL statement and it certaintly worth trying to set them to the same type.

Finally and that was the problem :

```
[Association(Name = "FK_OrdersLines_Orders", Storage = "_Items")]
```

should look like :

```
[Association(Name = "FK_OrdersLines_Orders", Storage = "_Items", OtherKey = "OrderID")]
```

Comment: Hi, I've temporarily changed those columns to not allow nulls, but I still get the same error. LINQ seems to be working fine if I query each table individually it is just failing to load OrderLines into Order._Items. For example `var line = from l in context.OrderLine where l.OrderID.Equals(this.OrderID) select l;'` will produce a collection of OrderLines I can then iterate over.

Comment: Another question, is the property DeferredLoadingEnabled set to false  for your OrderDataContext constructor or elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not explicitly setting it to anything so it should be using the default for DataContext, If I break after it is initialised it has DeferredLoadingEnabled set to true.

Comment: Ok thank you, so no problem with loading child entities i guess. I also noticed that orderId is nvarchar(30) and localLineId is int. It could "hurt" Linq2SQL to match these 2 primary keys while generating a join SQL statement. It certaintly worth trying to set them to the same type.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion has made me realise what I was doing wrong. With the decorator `[Association(Name = "FK_OrdersLines_Orders", Storage = "_Items")]` I had assumed the Name attribute would tell it to use the Foreign Key Constraint defined in the database to figure out how to set up the join. I added in the OtherKey attribute and set it to OrderID and it now works as expected. Also I'm new to posting here, what's the best way  to close this question?

Comment: Oops i'm was assuming the same and did not report it. Your question cannot be deleted anymore but you have 2 choices : 
- leave it like this
- or mark an answer as accepted if you think people will be able to fix the same issue with it (and its comments) and/or reward the people helping you if you think it is deserved ;)